# react query setQueryData options with staleTime not overriding config settings?

Tags: reactjs, react-query

Here is my global config:

```
  defaultOptions: {
    queries: {
      staleTime: 600000, // 10 minutes before fresh data becomes stale
      cacheTime: 900000, // 15 minutes before cache is emptied
      refetchOnMount: false,
      refetchOnReconnect: false,
      refetchOnWindowFocus: false,
      notifyOnChangeProps: 'tracked',
      retry: false,
      onError: queryErrorHandler,
    },
  },
```

Here is what I am doing somewhere else in the app. I do this because I am loading data from an outside source -

```
    queryClient.setQueryDefaults(userQueryKeys.all, { staleTime: Infinity, cacheTime: Infinity });
```

The issue is that the global settings are taking precedent. I can't have this entry "userQueryKeys.all" only for 10minutes - it needs to stay around for the life of the user on the page. But's resorting to the 10mins.

When I inspect my console for the queries - it shows the 900000 that is set globally.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be confusing the usage of [setDefaultOptions](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetdefaultoptions) with [setQueryDefaults](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/QueryClient#queryclientsetquerydefaults).

> setQueryDefaults can be used to set default options for specific queries: tsx

`queryClient.setQueryDefaults(['posts'], { queryFn: fetchPosts })`

> The setDefaultOptions method can be used to dynamically set the
> default options for this queryClient. Previously defined default
> options will be overwritten.

```
queryClient.setDefaultOptions({
  queries: {
    staleTime: Infinity,
  },
})
```

Comment: hmmm, but I want to set the stale/cache times for ONLY this cacheKey - otherwise, keep it how it is, in the config, for all others... that setDefaultOptions reads "previously defined default options will be overwritten".. that means my config will be overwritten no?

Comment: In any component where you instantiate `useQuery()`, you can pass in the `staleTime` and `cacheTime` which I think will let you have the same intended effect.

`const query = useQuery({ queryKey: ['todos'], queryFn: getTodos, staleTime: Infinity, cacheTime: Infinity })`

--- https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/reference/useQuery

Comment: That's the issue with my usage, I am manually setting: queryClient.setQueryData(userQueryKeys.all, user); // <-- this I want to extend with inifinity w/o affecting all my other routes.

Answer (score 0):

The defaults are taken into account at the time when the query is created. If you create the client with the default values, then create a query, then change the defaults, the new defaults will only be applied to queries created from that moment on - *not* for queries that already exist.

If you create the client, and then right after that set the defaults:

```
const queryClient = new QueryClient(...)
queryClient.setQueryDefaults(...)
```

it should work. please file an issue with a reproduction if it doesn't.

Comment: This seems odd, to me - can't we get a more granular approach and set defaults PER query, if needed? For example, I want usr/auth data to stick around for the life the session, BUT for other queries - I want just for 10 minutes... but then we can have a race condition of query creation taking precedence.. shouldn't we be able to set defaults per query?

Comment: not sure what you mean, we can set defaults per query. You just need to do it ahead of time, before the query is created...

Comment: maybe this helps: https://tkdodo.eu/blog/react-query-as-a-state-manager#bonus-using-setquerydefaults